# Como gerenciar uma conexão SQLite entre varias threads simultâneas?

Tags: android, sqlite, multithreading, async, sqlite3

Então estou enfrentando alguns problemas com minha conexão com o SQLite, onde não estou encontrando uma solução hábil.

**Cenário**

Meu cenário é o seguinte:

- Faço sincronização dos dados do meu aplicativo com um sistema legado, através de um WebService;
- Está sincronização é feita através de uma Thread que verifica o que há de novo na base legada e inicia varias outras Threads para obter os dados e salva-los em sua base local (SQLite);
- Para cada entidade que é encontrado novos dados na base legado é aberta uma nova Thread, (cada entidade tem um EndPoint, onde é acessado, baixado, e salvo os dados, e depois finalizada a Thread). Ex: se há novos clientes na base legada, é iniciada uma requisição que irá buscar todos os novos clientes, e salva-os em minha tabela de clientes no SQLite, isso executaria em uma Thread;

**Problema**

O problema é que mesmo que uso `AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR` que somente executa uma Thread por vez, entre uma abertura e outra de conexão acaba gerando problema de *Lock*, onde não consigo obter a referencia current da conexão e ao tentar criar um nova ele acusa que o db está *Locked*.

Acredito que meu problema nem é com as Threads executando simultaneamente, mas sim em minha `class` de gerenciamento de conexão, a que estou utilizando atualmente é está:

```java
public abstract class GConexaoAdapter {

private final DatabaseHelper mDbHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
protected final Context ctx;

public GConexaoAdapter(Context ctx, String dbName, int dbVersion) {
    this.mDbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(ctx, dbName, dbVersion);
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

private void open() {
    try {
        synchronized (ctx) {
            synchronized (mDbHelper) {
                if (mDb == null) {
                    mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                } else {
                    synchronized (mDb) {
                        mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if (mDb == null || !mDb.isOpen())
            mDb = ctx.openOrCreateDatabase(mDbHelper.getDatabaseName(), 0,
                    null);
        Log.i("TRATAR", "tratar");
    }
}

protected SQLiteDatabase getConexao() {
    synchronized (ctx) {
        synchronized (mDbHelper) {
            if (mDb == null) {
                this.open();
            } else if (!mDb.isOpen()) {
                synchronized (mDb) {
                    if (!mDb.isOpen()) {
                        this.open();
                    }
                }
            }
            return mDb;
        }
    }
}

protected void closeConexao() {
    synchronized (ctx) {
        synchronized (mDbHelper) {
            if (mDb != null && mDb.isOpen()) {
                synchronized (mDb) {
                    if (mDb.isOpen()) {
                        if (mDb.inTransaction()) {
                            mDb.endTransaction();
                        }
                        mDb.close();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        if (!db.isReadOnly()) {
            // db.execSQL("PRAGMA foreign_keys=ON;");
        }
    }

    DatabaseHelper(Context context, String dbNome, int dbVersion) {
        super(context, dbNome, null, dbVersion);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }
}
}
```

Acredito que nem necessito de todos os `synchronized` que tenho, é que já tentei diversas soluções que encontrei e nenhuma me trouxe o resultado esperado.

**Pergunta?**

Acredito que até haja uma **"Receita de Bolo"** para este tipo de gerenciamento de conexão. Pois não devo ser o único a necessitar de uma solução como está.

Então como faria para gerenciar de forma, eficaz minha conexão com o banco de dados SQLite?

## Observação muito importante:

> Gostaria de gerenciar a conexão SQLite entre várias thread simultâneas, porém **sem causar locks que acabam gerando exceções e violando a integridade dos dados**!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Então após, mais algum tempo de pesquisa, e seguindo alguns caminhos apontados por vocês, cheguei a uma **"Receita de Bolo*¹"** como eu procurava.

Vou mostrar qual a solução que atendeu as minhas necessidades:

Segui as dicas apontadas nesse [link](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/concurrent-database-access), fazendo algumas modificas para minhas necessidades

```java
public class DatabaseManager {
    private AtomicInteger mOpenCounter = new AtomicInteger();

private static DatabaseManager instance;
private static SQLiteOpenHelper mDatabaseHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase mDatabase;

    private DatabaseManager() {
        super();
    }

private static synchronized void initializeInstance(SQLiteOpenHelper helper) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseManager();
        mDatabaseHelper = helper;
    }
}

public static synchronized DatabaseManager getInstance(Context context,
        String dbName, int dbVersion) {
    if (instance == null) {
        initializeInstance(new DatabaseHelper(context, dbName, dbVersion));
        return instance;
    }

    return instance;
}

public synchronized SQLiteDatabase openDatabase() {
    if (mOpenCounter.incrementAndGet() == 1) {
        // Opening new database
        mDatabase = mDatabaseHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    }
    return mDatabase;
}

public synchronized void closeDatabase() {
    if (mOpenCounter.decrementAndGet() == 0) {
        // Closing database
        mDatabase.close();

    }
}
}
```

E em minha antiga `class` de controle fiz algumas modificações que só se aplicam para adaptar minha antiga `class` a nova `class` de gerenciamento de conexão:

```java
public abstract class GConexaoAdapter {

protected final Context ctx;
private final String dbName;
private final int dbVersion;

public GConexaoAdapter(Context ctx, String dbName, int dbVersion) {
    this.dbName = dbName;
    this.dbVersion = dbVersion;
    this.ctx = ctx;
}

protected SQLiteDatabase getConexao() {
    return DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, dbName, dbVersion)
            .openDatabase();
}

protected void closeConexao() {
    DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, dbName, dbVersion).closeDatabase();
}
}
```

Essa segunda `class` não é necessária você pode utilizar a `DatabaseManager` diretamente dessa maneira:

```java
private long create(ContentValues valores) {
    try {
        DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, "db", 1).openDatabase()
                .beginTransaction();
        long result = DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, "db", 1).openDatabase().insert(nomeTabela, null, valores);
        DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, "db", 1).openDatabase().setTransactionSuccessful();
        return result;
    } finally {
        DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, "db", 1).openDatabase().endTransaction();
        DatabaseManager.getInstance(ctx, "db", 1).closeDatabase();
    }
}
```

Ou adapta-la a sua forma de trabalho.

*¹Não é uma receita de bolo como realmente era esperado pela pergunta, mas para meu caso em especifico e acredito que para outros também, será muito útil, e pode ser facilmente adaptado ao seu ambiente, se estiver trabalhando de forma modular e organizada.

> Obs: Está solução gerencia a conexão do **SQLite** em **thread-safe**

Comment: Hmmm... solução interessante. Só complementando, por ser um singleton creio que `DatabaseManager` deveria ter um construtor privado e o método `initializeInstance()` também deveria ser privado.

Comment: Sim você tem razão, não me ative a esses detalhes, tem que restringir ao máximo o acesso por se tratar de um **singleton**

Comment: A desvantagem dessa solução é que o usuário pode fazer besteira e chamar `close()` diretamente no objeto retornado por `openDatabase()`, o que causaria problema ao usar o objeto novamente (mesmo se for o retorno de outro `openDatabase()`), não?

Comment: Na verdade como os métodos `openDatabase()` e `closeDatabase()` são sincronizados esse `AtomicInteger` pode ser trocado por um simples _null check_ sobre a variável `mDatabase`. Se o desenvolvedor não tiver noção da forma como deve usar `openDatabase()` e `closeDatabase()` e manipular livremente o objeto `SQLiteDatabase` retornado, essa solução continua sendo problemática como caso geral ou receita de bolo.

Comment: Talvez não seja uma receita de bolo para caso geral, mais uma ótima solução? Ou você quer dizer que isso não funciona conforme esperado? E um desenvolvedor deve entender o proposito do código para depois implementa-lo, nada é tão simples a esse ponto. E detalhes para mim esse solução caiu como uma luva.

Comment: Funciona para o seu caso particular e agora, que você está se lembrando de fechar a conexão via `closeDatabase()`. Você pode até frisar isso no Javadoc da classe, mas é fácil esquecer isso no futuro e aí a classe perde a sua utilidade.

Answer (score 3):

Sincronizar os métodos de abertura, leitura/gravação e fechamento do banco individualmente não resolve um problema essencial que é a necessidade do acesso ao banco ser atômico.

Facilitaria sua vida se ao invés de usar esse monte de `synchronized` dentro dessa classe (sincronizar em um `Context` ??) você usasse dentro do método `doInBackground()` de suas `AsyncTask`s, envolvendo dentro de um bloco `synchronized` uma operação atômica no banco composta de `open()`, ler ou gravar, `close()`:

```java
doInBackground() {

    //Traz os dados do webservice;

    synchronized(objetoLock) {
        open();
        //lê ou grava no banco;
        close();
    }
}
```

Também sugiro que você use como lock dos blocos `synchronized` um objeto que dure ao longo de toda a aplicação, eu faria uso de um objeto à parte exclusivo para isso, mas você pode usar um objeto relacionado ao banco (por exemplo a instância de `GConexaoAdapter`) desde que ele dure tempo suficiente em sua aplicação para ser usado por todas as operações em banco que ocorrerem. E não custa frisar, a sincronização tem que ser feita sempre no mesmo objeto, senão dá problema de acesso concorrente do mesmo jeito.

Comment: Compreendi sua sugestão, e parece ser útil, mais o gerenciamento de conexão não deve se restringir as threads mas a qualquer chamada de conexão. Acredito que poderia controlar a conexão mantendo uma única instância no objeto **GConexaoAdapter**, só estou buscando uma maneira de fazer isso bem. Estou trabalhando [nessa](http://blog.lemberg.co.uk/concurrent-database-access) idéia

Comment: Em qualquer acesso ao banco você vai ter que usar o `synchronized()` para evitar chamadas concorrentes a `getWritableDatabase()`. Não dá pra fazer de outro jeito. A única alternativa seria criar métodos `insert()`, `delete()`, etc. no `GConexaoAdapter`, todos eles `synchronized`, e dentro de cada um você chama `getWritableDatabase()` antes de executar a operação propriamente dita e `close()` em seguida.

Comment: _"para evitar chamadas concorrentes a getWritableDatabase()"_ - leia-se _"para garantir a operação atômica composta por `mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase()` e `mDb.close()`"_

Comment: sua resposta me ajudou a achar o caminho das pedras, confira minha solução.

Answer (score 1):

Recomendo fortemente usar uma fila externa (Existem varias soluções prontas para isso) para a inserção continua... e separar uma unica thread para função de consumi-la... não vai gerar lock e vai garantir a integridade cronológica dos dados.. só não vai ser síncrono com a leitura dos dados na base original..

Comment: mais em thread simultâneas o desempenho em sincronização de uma grande quantidade de dados é muito melhor pois utiliza o máximo da conexão disponível no momento, pois enquanto esta fazendo 'insert' em alguns dados na base a outra thread está baixando o JSON do endpoint, e assim por diante, e a solução que postei já está funcionando para mim em thread-safe.

Comment: sim, nao falei para deixar de usar threads para as outras funções mas enfileirar a escrita no banco... podendo inclusive ler mais de um item da fila e condensar a escrita de 2 ou 3 itens por vez, diminuindo bastante o I/O

Answer (score 0):

Comece com o padrão "quem abre a conexão é quem a fecha", me desculpe não saber se existe um nome cool para este padrão... :-)

Implementar a interface DataSource te ajuda a definir como você vai trabalhar com a única conexão no banco.

acho que este pode ser um caminho... :-)

Comment: Flávio Granato não tenho certeza, mais pelo que vi está interface não é especifica para trabalhar com conexões SQLiteDataBase, e pesquisando aqui sobre ela, não vi benefícios em utiliza-la? pode me da um exemplo?

Comment: Pense que seu método **getConnection()** retornará a conexão e que seu datasource só terá uma conexão ativa, mas somente se não houver transação ativa. Assim você pode gerenciar as conexõa... (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4075778/how-do-i-implement-getconnection-in-datasource-in-java)

Comment: Mais o **DataSource** pelo que percebo é uma interface para gerenciamento de conexões em **Java** em geral onde o **getConnection()** retorna um objeto **Connection** é o SQLite um objeto **SQLiteDatabase**

Comment: Qual o problema de ter um datasource? http://sourceforge.net/p/sqlite-connpool/home/Home/ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525444/how-to-connect-sqlite-with-java

Comment: acho que implementar essa interface não me ajudará a tornar minha conexão **thread-safe**, parece ser um esforço desnecessário.

Comment: Enfim, ela é o caminho para seu código ficar mais semântico. Se você criar um singleton e sempre retornar esta instância... por ai vai...

Answer (score 0):

Não entendo muito de android, mas temos uma aplicação desktop que também utiliza SQLite e a solução para o uso dela em várias threads foi criar uma classe para ser um Pool de conexões sendo que esse pool tinha somente 1 conexão para escrita e 2 para leitura